# Does ExpiresByType text/css rule affect all .css files on the site?

Tags: css, .htaccess, file-type, expires-header

Does the following rule affect all .css files on the site or just in root or in some folder?

```
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
```

Comment: `text/css` is the MIME type, so it would be everything on the site with that MIME type (all .css files)

Comment: Thanks, can't give you a poit for it tough cause you commented it but you made me happy anyway :)